# How to select multiple entities from a left-sidebar in aframe inspector?

Tags: javascript, html, css, aframe

I'm new to JS and Aframe technologies. I want to implement multiple entity selections using the control key from the keyboard for the example that has been provided in Aframe website under WebVR tab. The link to the site is https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/helloworld/
In this link please go to the visual inspector. 
When the visual inspector opens the left sidebar can select only one entity at once. My requirement is that it should select multiple entities using the cntrl key from the keyboard. How can I implement this?

Comment: The inspector does not support this. You can file an issue (https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-inspector/issues) requesting the feature, but would probably need to explain more how selecting multiple entities would be useful.

Comment: Thank You Don !!
But my work requires me to have this implementation. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to select multiple entities? I assume you then want to edit all selected entities at once? You could add the feature to the inspector, I suppose, but that's quite a lot to ask in an SO question, and more than I can answer.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is partially correct as I do not want to edit the entities but move those entities in space at once. I think I did ask a lot on SO. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Why are [tag:three.js] and [tag:aframe] being mixed and matched? The visual inspector from the link looks like a DOM exclusive thing, belonging to this particular library. What does `three.js` have to do with all this, with this question? I'm removing the threejs tag

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an answer: not supported and unclear of the use case.